# Зачем нужен "string?" (именно с вопросом а не просто "string")?

Tags: c#, .net

В описании `Object` увидел, что метод `ToString()` возвращает `string?`. Возник вопрос, зачем? Ведь `string` - ссылочный тип и может сам иметь значение `null`. Есть какая-то разница или эту обёртку добавили только чтобы подчеркнуть что метод может вернуть `null`?

[image: строка 82]

Comment: `ToString` возвращает **строковое** представление объекта. Для строк используется тип `string` - другого типа просто нет.

Comment: @Grundy Мне не верите - откройте декларацию Object в пространстве имён System. Сейчас добавлю скрин в вопрос

Comment: А :-) не увидел, что `?` это часть типа. Да, это именно потому, что возвращаемое значение может быть в том числе и `null`

Comment: Тут дело в новой версии `C#` и директиве `#nullable enable`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В C# 8 добавились [Nullable reference types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).

При использовании директивы

```
#nullable enable
```

для того, чтобы показать что ссылочный тип так же может принимать `null`, ему нужно добавить `?` по аналогии со значимыми `Nullable` типами.

Answer (score 3):

Дело тут в обратной совместимости.

В старых версиях C# ссылочные типы были все nullable (то есть, могли «законно» принимать значение `null`). Виртуальная функция `object.ToString()` была определена тогда.

Сейчас менять определение на не-nullable-вариант уже поздно, так как код пользователя, написанный ранее, имел полное право возвращать `null`, и если «корневая» виртуальная функция поменяет свою сигнатуру, многим придётся переписывать свой код.

Так что этот поезд уже ушёл, к сожалению. Но да, если бы C# проектировался сегодня с нуля, возвращаемый тип метода `object.ToString()` скорее всего сделали бы `string`, а не `string?`.